# How to do group by range query

Tags: apache-spark

I am building a Spark app for querying big log data from MS Ping Server.

I have a Java class which creates the context and loads the file, and I also have a Java parser to parse it and load it into a DataFrame.

I am able to create the SQLContext successfully and queries work as well.

The log table looks like this(on the SQLContext)

```
Timestamp | pfhost | Response Time
```

I would like get the average response time per server for each hour interval for the whole day.

How to make that query?

Comment: First I would start with writing the same query in plain SQL, and then try converting it to a SQLContext query (which is quite similar). SQLContext uses the HiveQL language, here's a nice cheat sheet for converting: http://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2013/08/Hortonworks.CheatSheet.SQLtoHive.pdf
If you get stuck, you can post a question about your problem, but you can't expect us to do your work for you :)

Comment: :) I know its pretty difficult. I wouod rather goto Database forum